# SQL output modification: NULL to String

Tags: sql-server, date

I am using sql to retrieve two dates. I formatted the first date with CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date, 110). This changes the output to 12-08-2013 (for example).

Now, I want the second date to be formatted the same way UNLESS it is = to NULL, in which case it should come out as 00-00-0000.

```
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_opened, 110) AS opened,

     --IF date_closed = 'NULL' return '00-00-0000' AS closed 
     --ELSE return CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_closed, 110) AS closed,
```

Is there any way to apply this specific formatting to the output? I cannot modify the underlying database.

Comment: is this Oracle? or another database - there are some answers but may be RDBMS specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_closed, 110), '00-00-0000')  AS [closed]
```

OR

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_closed, 110), '00-00-0000')  AS [closed]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
    CASE WHEN date_closed IS NULL THEN '00-00-0000' 
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_Closed, 110) END AS closed
```